# Calling function from service in controller angular ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I have a layout page with a login button, I only want to show it when I am not logged in. I want to achieve this by using a service:

```
app.service('AuthService', function ($http) {
        this.getUserStatus = function () {
            return $http({
                url: '/auth/status',
                method: "GET"
            });
        };
});
```

Then I call it in a controller like so:

```
app.controller('MenuController', [
  '$scope',
  '$http',

function ($scope, AuthService) {

    $scope.authorize = function() {
      AuthService.getUserStatus();
    }
  }
]);
```

Lastly I use ng-controller and ng-hide in the layout to show or hide the logout button:

```
<body ng-app="headcountApp">
<nav ng-controller="MenuController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-hide="authorize">
      <a href="#/">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/employee/add">Add</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/employees">employees</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/edit">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/delete">Delete</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/logout">logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My problem is that it's always hidden, telling me the value is always true. How can I fix this?

This fixed the problem:

```
app.controller('MenuController', [
'$scope',
'$http',
'AuthService',

function ($scope, $http, AuthService) {

$scope.authorized = false;
  AuthService.getUserStatus().then(function(res){
    $scope.authorized = res.data;
   });
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AuthService.getUserStatus();` return the result of [$http()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). the result of `$http()` call is a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). you need to register a resolve callback with promise to get the result of http request:

```
$scope.authorized = false;
$scope.authorize = function() {
    AuthService.getUserStatus().then(function(res){
         // If result from server indicate login state set $scope.authorized = true
    });
}
```

And in your view bind to `$scope.authorize`:

```
<li ng-hide="authorized">
  <a href="#/">Login</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Your updated example is still wrong because you're using `'http'` instead of `'AuthService'` when specifying your dependencies for the injector.

Comment: I had to use AuthService but the function was undefined because the controller still needed $http. It is fixed now though, I have updated my answer with the solution.